# How to make a job that doesn't depend on a matrix only run once

Tags: github-actions

I have a GitHub Actions workflow containing a `setup` job:

```yaml
setup:
  runs-on: windows-latest
  steps:
    - name: Checkout Repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2.4.0
    - name: Install .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1.8.2
      with:
        dotnet-version: 6.0.x
```

and once `setup` is complete, I build for my for target platforms:

```yaml
build:
  needs:
    - setup
  runs-on: windows-latest
  strategy:
    matrix:
      target:
        - win-x64
        - linux-x64
        - linux-arm64
        - osx-x64
      self-contained:
        - self-contained
        - framework-dependent
  steps:
    - name: Checkout Repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2.4.0
    - name: Install .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1.8.2
      with:
        dotnet-version: 6.0.x
    - name: Build
      run: >-
        dotnet publish -r ${{matrix.target}} --self-contained ${{
        matrix.self-contained == 'self-contained' }} ${{ matrix.self-contained
        && '' || '/p:DisablePatch="--nopatch"' }}
```

In `build`, I end up duplicating the work done by `setup`—8 times. Is there a way to avoid this, and perhaps just copy the machine state from `setup` into the `build` job?

Answer (score 1):

When you run an action (in your job steps), it will only apply to the runner used to execute the job steps.

According to the [Github documentation about matrix](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-a-build-matrix-for-your-jobs), each matrix job runs in parallel. Therefore they will all need the setup to be executed as each provided runner starts without the `Checkout Repository` and `Install .NET` steps configured.

You can't share those setup between the runners provided by Github, because each job will use a new (and different) runner.

*Which means your `setup` job here won't do anything that requires the `needs` configuration on the `build` job, as what it does will only applies to itself.*

*Therefore, removing the `needs: setup` on the `build` job would be the same as what you did.*

**What you could do instead** for example, is using [self-hosted runners](https://docs.github.com/pt/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/about-self-hosted-runners) with dotnet already installed, or a [docker image](https://dev.to/mihinduranasinghe/using-docker-containers-in-jobs-github-actions-3eof). In that case you wouldn't need to setup dotnet every time, but is it worth the cost? (as building a docker image can take more time that doing the setup, so you should evaluate this first).

Comment: Can I wholly remove the `setup` job itself?

Comment: Yes, it should work the same without it (be sure to remove the `needs` field from the `build` subsequent job as well).